# about proof of Markov's inequality

Tags: probability

I want to prove the following proposition.

proposition: let **X** be a random variable in (Ω,Σ,P) with a distribution function **F** and **∫**(̠-∞,∞)**|x|^2dF**<**∞**. Then ,for every **a>0, P[|X|≧a]**≦**E(X^2)/a^2**

In this proposition,  expected value is defined by Stieltjes integral. Then, I am tying to prove in the following steps.

First, for every **u < a, E(X^2)=∫(̠-∞,∞)x^2dF=∫[u,∞)x^2dF+∫[-a,u]x^2dF+∫(̠-∞,-a]x^2dF≧(u^2)P[X>u]+(a^2)P[X≦-a]**

Second, let **u→a-0**.

Is these steps right? Are there more simple proofs?

Comment: Note that $\mathbb E[X^2] = \mathbb E[X^2 \chi_{(|X| \ge a)}] + \mathbb E[X^2 \chi_{(|X| < a)}] \ge \mathbb E[a^2 \chi_{(|X| \ge a)}] + 0 = a^2 \mathbb P(|X| \ge a)$

It is the simpliest proof, I'm familiar with

Comment: Equivalently, $\chi_{|X|\ge a}\le|X/a|^2$, so $P(|X|\ge a)=E[\chi_{|X|\ge a}]\le E[|X/a|^2]$.

Comment: That is very simple. Thank you very mach.